# iOS Collection View Scrolling Lags

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am using a UI Collection View to display cells with images and its associated data (like date, name) in a vertical scrolling format. The image data is fetched from the server when the view appears. The fetched data is then converted to UIImage when the cell appears.

The issue is scrolling is laggy. Everytime a new cell is about to appear, the scrolling hangs up a little. Is there a way to solve this problem? I was thinking of starting the conversion of NSData to UIImage in a background thread to prevent lag. Not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: Use SDWebImage with a placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stack says, you should be loading the images asynchronously, and there are wonderful `UIImageView` categories that make this really easy to do, namely the category in [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or in [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). These `UIImageView` categories not only load images asynchronously, but also do caching, cancel network operations if necessary, etc. It takes a lot of code if you do this properly yourself (capturing all of those features I just enumerated), but it's really easy if you use one of these categories.

For example, if using SDWebImage, you can:

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

and then:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%s: setImageWithURL error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}];
```

Or, if using AFNetworking:

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
```

and

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

or

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] success:nil failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%s: setImageWithURLRequest error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}];
```